# CakePHP putting `id` = '1' in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to update a row with the following command, but CakePHP always put a `'1'` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
# the PHP command
$this->Administrator->id = $id; # id = 6, it wasn't changed
$this->Administrator->save($this->request->data);

-- simplified version of the generated SQL
UPDATE `someTable`  SET `someField` = 'value', `id` = '6' WHERE `id` = '1'
```

It's interesting that the `id` is correct in the generated SQL in the update part, but not in the `WHERE` clause, and yes, the `id` column is the primary key in the table. I'm using the last version of CakePHP.

What I'm doing wrong? How the `id` in the `WHERE` clause can be `6`?

**EDIT:** It produces the same result with the generated code with Bake. Maybe a problem in the model or database?

**EDIT 2:** I'm logging all the queries and before trying to update, CakePHP perform some `SELECT count(*)` and it uses the `WHERE id = 6`.

**EDIT 3:** Insert, delete and read works fine.

---

### Final update: problem solved

I'm not sure what happened, but I think that I solved the problem.

First, the update wasn't working event with the code generated with Bake.

Second, only the update of Administrators aren't working, all the others are ok.

Third, I think the problem came from a column in the `administrators` table that is also called `administrators` and it is a `TINYINT(1)`. I changed the column name to `administrators_area`, changed some code too and all worked.

I think this column was creating some conflict and because this, the UPDATE wasn't working. Before trying this, I changed the table name to `users` keeping the column as `administrators` and worked too.

If the problem wasn't a conflict between table name and table column with the same name, it was a great coincidence that the problem solved after I changed the name.

Comment: your `$this->Administrator` object has id 1 I guess. You change that to 6 and save it, so the query says: "make id 6" for the object "that has id 1".

Comment: @Nanne, I tried to use `create()` to reset the id of the object. In both cases, using or not, the `id` of the object is `null`.

Comment: debug() the data - is 'id' already in the data?

Comment: @Dave, yes, it is. It comes with the value of 6 as string like the other parameters.

Comment: If it's already got the id, then don't set the id manually prior to the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$this->request->data['Administrator']['id'] = $id; // <-- Line changed
$this->Administrator->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: I tried, but doesn't work. The `$this->request->data['Administrator']['id']` already has the value of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building this submission from a form? What do you have in your form on the View? My first guess is that you are neglecting to include the hidden input for id that tells CakePHP what Model object we are updating:

```
echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

What sort of data are you receiving if you call these functions?

```
debug($this->request->data);
debug($this->Administrator);
```

If its not an issue with the form itself I would be suspicious only because they ID=1 should really only come from some residual data or an unset model.

Comment: I'm using the form the ID as you wrote and it is coming in the POST request. All the other fields are expected too. But tell me more about unset mode, maybe can be this. That code is the only code that I'm using to save inside the controller action.